# Tool for visualizing TFS 2010 Storyboard

Tags: tfs, agile, storyboard

I need a tool to clearly present a story board to my development team on a daily basis that shows the iteration stories and the tasks that need to be done. I've tried TFS Workbench v2.2, but found that it doesn't make efficient use of the screen which is critical when using a projector and showing off to the whole team.

Previously I've used tools like XPlanner and Rally which were friendlier to use, but my current project stores everything in TFS so I have to have tight integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you given Telerik Work Item Manager and Project Dashboard a try?

http://www.telerik.com/agile-project-management-tools/tfsmanager-and-tfsdashboard.aspx

Okay, so it's not a web app, but I've found it fairly useful.

Comment: Not being a web app turns out to be a great thing. The Project Dashboard is a bit of data overload/screen vomit, but the Work Item Manager is brilliant. I'm surprised it doesn't turn up in more queries.

Comment: It seems it is not updated anymore and there are some issues with it. It's still a beta.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://urbanturtle.com/.  It's integrated with Team Web Access and does pretty well on larger screens.  There are a number of convenient things built in which make it a pretty good active digital board.

Comment: Urban Turtle seems to be a favorite recommendation(I've never used it), but my Director frowned as soon as I mentioned it. Hopefully there is another option.

Comment: Why'd he frown?  By the way take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/06/14/agile-project-management-in-visual-studio-alm-v-next.aspx.  Go with Urban Turtle for now and you'll have much the same thing in vNext.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I suspect the pricing got him. He wants a tool everyone can look at, but when you add up all the developers, testers, and managers you're looking at north of $10k.

Comment: I haven't used Urban Turtle so take this with a grain of salt.  The demos look cool and useful, but the price is an absolute killer.  It would be okay if the initial price were high, but it sounds like there's an annual renewal of 50% of the original price.  That's gouging.

Comment: The price is around 100$ per user. http://urbanturtle.com/pricing This is more than half the price when compared to other tools. Also, the license is perpetual. The renewal price only applies to support and maintenance. The product will continue to work as expected but you will not be able to upgrade to a new version. This is a pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMStack) could be a good solution for this. It offers integration with TFS, the taskboard is designed to be informative on a small or a big screen and it has nice additional features such as time tracking and reports.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AgileWrap](http://www.agilewrap.com).

It has a built-in Taskboard that shows story and task cards for an iteration. You can project Taskboard on a big screen during daily meeting and update status of stories, tasks and defects. If you have some data in external system that you cannot move to AgileWrap then you can store external system's hyperlinks in the description and comments (links are clickable) of stories and tasks for reference.

Take a look at [TaskBoard video at YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUYtyNwfCuc).

Comment: I can't bring up the YouTube video, but going through the documentation it doesn't appear to have any integraton with TFS. Did I miss something or didn't you see that part of my question?